# How do I get metrics for youtube users?

Tags: youtube

I am new to youtube APIs, I am trying the API explorer here : https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/

I am trying to get details about a particular youtube user. I am entering the following things to execute the method in the API explorer :
channel id, start date, end date and metrics. When I execute i get the following 403 Forbidden error with **you do not have permission to execute this method** as a message.

All the details I am entering are correct.

Does youtube doesnt allow to fetch details of other users ? If it allows, what am I doing wrong here? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are a CMS that manages the channel you are requesting data for, Youtube will not allow you to access their analytics data. The analytics API only allows you to request data for the channels owned by the current authenticated user.

Comment: Thanks Rob. But I believe there is a way out. There are analytics start ups out there who churn out metrics for other channels also (channels not owned by you). For ex: see tubelytics,com , I am sure there is a way !! Also, as a user i would always want to know how my competitor channels are doing. Any help here would be highly appreciated.!

Comment: This is not done via _unauthorized_ analytics access, which again, is not possible. On the surface, it appears that they are getting public info from the data api (views, subscribers, etc) and estimating the income based on an algorithm they wrote. I'm sure they have viewed quite a bit of views/subscribers:income data to develop this algorithm, but I assure you they are not performing unauthorized requests to the analytics API.